# Failure to deserialize with [FromBody] tag

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api, deserialization, uwp

I'm got an api endpoint I'm trying to hit that uses the [FromBody] tag with an object in the parameter line like so:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("update")]
public IHttpActionResult MyWebApiMethod([FromBody] MyObject objectValue)
{
```

I've been writing a UWP app that communicates with this web api, and I've successfully hit the endpoint just fine before; however, for whatever reason, as of lately, I can no longer hit this specific endpoint.  The controller for the api initiliazes, and when I enable tracing, I can see the controller has managed to associate the correct endpoint, and seems to have deduced that the data model of the object I'm sending matches the one the api is expecting, but when it goes to do the deserialization as a result of the [FromBody] tag, it just goes into never never land, and doesn't do anything.  Eventually my app times out with its request.

Out of many tests I did to try and resolve what was causing this issue.  I found 2 notable things, but I can't figure out how to fix the root issue.

First off, was a temporary workaround. If I changed the endpoint to receive a JObject instead and used

```
var newValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(JsonConvert.Serialize(objectValue);
```

then, the endpoint would get hit, and my `newValue` would be properly deserialized.

Second, going with the chance that my datamodel on the client was different than the one our api was using, I turned the data model into a nuget (I'm having issues making this nuget compatible for Universal Windows 10 apps due to some reference issues, so I made a normal Class Library) then install the nuget into a fairly bare bones console application, and made the same call to the same endpoint, and it hit the end point fine without having to resort to using JObject in the method parameter.

So, somewhere, somehow, the deserialization process happening when the data packet comes from a Universal app is different than the one coming from a generic console application.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to tie into this deserialization process when the `[FromBody]` takes over before going into the Method.

Any help on resolving this issue would be great.

Comment: What does the `MyObject` class contains? how are you making the http request? We need a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help you...

Comment: You don't need that `[FromBody]`. Even if you don't mentioned it you can still myobject as form body.

Comment: Can you use Fiddler to inspect the http request from the UWP app and see if the fields are being transmitted over the wire?

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli yes, we did check Fiddler for this.  There seems to be nothing in the object capture from fiddler that would cause this problem.  Additionally, I wouldn't be able to give an example of this as the code base this problem is part of is huge. Pulling out everything I can't share here, and putting into a small example would take days...  I don't believe what the MyObject class contains would be relevant.  But, there's a few strings, a few ints, a Guid, and a few virtual lists of other objects.  Before you ask, yes I verified all those objects as well